# Load a .mov video in python from S3 via Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto, botocore

I am trying to load a .mov video file into a Lambda python script for processing.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3
import os

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = os.environ['SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')

    try:
        video = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        print(video)
        return event
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```

The 'video' object in-code is a dictionary, containing a 'Body' key with the value '<botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f0c0d4ec310'. I have tried a number of approaches to read this, including:

`video = video['Body'].read()`

which returns Bytes. When I try to read the bytes with open(...) or BytesIO, I get the error: "endswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str".

I have also tried

`video = video['Body'].read().decode()`

which returns error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 29: invalid start byte.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Looks like `video['Body'].read()` is already what you want.

Comment: This returns an invalid byte string. I am simply trying to read the video file as an object to be processed within the python script. Would you know any way to read a video object from bytes?

Comment: What library are you using to process the data?  Does it expect a local filename, or can it parse a bytes object, or does it need something like an io.BytesIO object to mimic a file handle?

Comment: `.decode()` tries to interpret the bytes as UTF-8 encoded text. But it's a video file, not text. I don't know how to decode .mov files.

Comment: I am trying to rip the audio from the video file using the moviepy library.

Comment: The moviepy library only seems to allow filenames, so you'll need to write the contents of the file to a local file in `/tmp/whatever.avi` and point moviepy at that.